# How can I sort a json that contains win and loss data for each user as a key in C#?

Tags: c#, json, linq

Right now, I have a json such as

```
{
  "Bob": {
    "Wins": 4,
    "Loses" : 5
  },
  "Dave": {
    "Wins": 8,
    "Loses" : 2
  },
  "Mike": {
    "Wins": 4,
    "Loses" : 2
  }
}
```

I'd like to sort each player first by number of wins, and if two or more players have the same number of wins, than the player with the least number of losses is ranked higher. For this example, it would be Dave, Mike, Bob. Is there a `LINQ`  query that I can use to efficiently sort this? Ideally, I'd like an array or list that returns them in order.

Comment: 1. Design a class to hold your data then serialise your JSON data to this class and then 2. sort the class using `linq`. Googling both of those separately will show you what to do and hopefully help with learning rather than having someone write your code for you.

Answer (score 3):

You can Deserialize the Json to collection, sort it as per needs, and then serialize it back again.

For example,

```
var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,Result>>(json);
var sortedDictionary = results.Select(kvp => new {User=kvp.Key,Result=kvp.Value})
                              .OrderByDescending(x=>x.Result.Wins)
                              .ThenBy(x=>x.Result.Loses)
                              .ToDictionary(key=>key.User,
                                          value=>new Result
                                                 { 
                                                     Wins = value.Result.Wins,
                                                     Loses=value.Result.Loses
                                                 }
                                            );
var sortedJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sortedDictionary);
```

Where Result is defined as

```
public class Result
{
    public int Wins{get;set;}
    public int Loses{get;set;}
}
```

Output

```
{"Dave":{"Wins":8,"Loses":2},"Mike":{"Wins":4,"Loses":2},"Bob":{"Wins":4,"Loses":5}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Separate the reading of your JSON from your sorting into two functions:

- ReadJSon: input your Json data; output a sequence of objects that contains the read data
- Sort: input your sequence of read JSON data, output the requested sort

The advantages are that the code in each  method will be fairly small. The code will be easier to understand, easier to reuse, for instance if you want to do other things with the JSON than sorting, easier to change and easier to unit test.

First of all you need a class to store the results of the players in:

```
class PlayerResult
{
    public Name {get; set;}
    ... // possible other properties
    public int Wins {get; set;}
    public int Losses {get; set;}
}
```

Then you need a procedure to read the JSON into a sequence of PlayerResults:

```
IEnumerable<PlayerResult> ReadJson(...)
{
    // TODO: implement
}
```

How you read the JSON depends on your input: is it a file? a Stream? a JsonReader?

If you don't know how to read JSON from a class / stream, visit [NewtonSoft Json.NET documentation](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm)

Once you've got the sequence of PlayerResults, the sorting is easy:

```
IOrderedEnumerable<PlayerResult> OrderByWinsAndLosses(this IEnumerable<PlayerResult> playerResults)
{
    return playerResults.OrderByDescending(playerResult => playerResult.Wins)
                        .ThenBy(playerResult => playerResult.Losses);
}
```

The `OrderByDescending` will put the player with the most wins first. The `ThenBy` will make sure that if two players have the same Wins, that the one with the least Losses comes first.

I return `IOrderedEnumerable` instead of `IEnumerable` to enable callers to add a ThenBy after calling my function.

Usage looks very much like LINQ, and you can add LINQ methods in front or after `OrderByWinsAndLoses`

```
var result = ReadJson(...)
    .Where(player => player.Name.StartsWith("A")
    .OrderByWinsAndLosses()
    .OrderBy(player => player.Name)
    .ToList();
```